# MongoDB default items with user overwrite

Tags: mongodb, collections, database

So the problem seems very simple but every way I approach the solution it seems to be a poor implementation approach with either duplicated content or messy data.

### The Problem

I want to provide an option for “overwrites” per user on “default” items. Basically I have a mongodb database with a collection containing items with the following information:

- ID
- Name
- Icon
- Description

There is a set of 20-30 items in this collection, which each user using the app views.

Most users will be happy to see the default but if a user wishes to say change the icon for an item or the name then how do I handle this “overwrite” on the ”default” item for just that single user.

### Possible solutions

My thoughts are to implement one of the following options but all just seem a little wrong (I have provided my thoughts on this):

- for each “overwriten” item add a duplicated item to the collection with the changes and a user_id field to link the user - this seems like a little bit of duplicated content as the user might only change the icon and not the name/description. Also if the name is changed int eh future on the default item how do you handle this and also how do you understand that this item must replace one of the “defaults” for just that user. I worry it will be a little bit of a performance issue too when looking up the items and then replacing the changed item
- having all the items duplicated per user in the same collection - very much duplication of content but might be the best performing option but could cause issues in the future if new “default” items need to be added or default options need changing
- collection per user - same as the previous. This options seems all kinds of wrong but maybe I’m just new to this and it is actually the best option.
- collection containing overwrites - this seems like a good idea but equally a bad one due to looking up and comparing. If everything is changed then why not just have all new items rather than effectively a find a replace.

#### Reason for wanting to get this right

Maybe I’m over thinking this but it seems like I will face this issue a lot and I think I need to get it right to remove future issues with performance, data management and updates to default items.

Comment: Not sure I really understand—probably easier if you could post some sample code/DB. Roughly my first idea would be a separate table with relationships setup for `icon` though.